# Learning Node - Express Public folder not working

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

So I'm new to node and trying to learn how to use the `express` library with it. However, the problem I'm trying to figure out is why the files in my `/public` folder do not seem to be served as static content.

Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars');
var path = require('path');

var application = express();

application.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

application.engine('handlebars', handlebars({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));

application.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.handlebars', { someProp: 3 });
});

application.listen(port);
```

And my directory structure:

```
/
  - server.js (the above referenced file)
  / Views
    - index.handlebars
    / Layouts
      - main.handlebars
  / public
    - ServeMe.txt
```

My understanding was that `application.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` was supposed to configure the server to respond to any request under the public folder with that resource if found. What am I doing wrong? Funnily enough, it was easier to configure handlebars as the view engine than to get this public folder working =D

EDIT: The full URL I am trying to request: 
`http://localhost:1337/public/serveme.txt`

I've tried case sensitivity (which should be a non-issue), and that also did not work.

Comment: is there an error message?

Comment: It just 404's, so the server doesn't seem to know how to handle the request.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> The full URL I am trying to request:  `http://localhost:1337/public/serveme.txt`

That's your problem. Anything inside the directory you designate as static content is made available directly from the base URL. You need to request `http://localhost:1337/serveme.txt` instead.

If you want to only serve static files from `/public` you can pass a string as the first argument:

```
application.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. Is there any way to force inclusion of the public url? I guess this is just another convention I will have to get used to.

Comment: @Tejs - I've updated my answer with a way to do that. You can pass a string as the first argument of any middleware function and if the requested URL does not match the function will not run.

Answer (score 31):

From the [Express API reference](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This line serves your public folder at your app's root URL, meaning the following requests are valid and don't give a 404 error.

`// GET /javascripts/jquery.js
// GET /style.css
// GET /favicon.ico`

app.use takes an optional first argument as well that allows you to specify which request URL you want to serve content at.  This first argument defaults to "/", meaning your static content will be served at the base URL.  If you want your static content to be served not at the root level, like your code currently does, check out the following example (again taken from the docs)

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This line serves your public folder again, but at your app's /static URL, making the following requests valid without a 404 error.

(Example URL: `http://localhost:1337/static/anythingInYourPublicFolder`)

`// GET /static/javascripts/jquery.js
// GET /static/style.css
// GET /static/favicon.ico`

Answer (score 3):

What URLs are you trying to load? You should **not** include "public" in your URLs, so `curl -v 'http://localhost:1337/ServeMe.txt'`.